# BIND redirect host without zone

Tags: unix, redirection, domain-name, bind, master

How can I redirect some hosts with my bind server, Like a hots file ( /etc/hosts ).
If I declare a master zone of a external domain, I can't resolve request for subdomain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with BIND. Consider using [Unbound](http://unbound.net/) for your resolver. It has this capability via `local-zone: <zone> transparent`.

Important: If the domain you are trying to override/redirect is protected with DNSSEC, the RR signatures will be absent if you do this. Some clients may refuse to resolve the name, and others may still resolve it but they will know that the data have been tampered with.

Comment: I tried it and it works!